# Qt: Fixed size policy?

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a mdi area that contains 3 sub-windows.I fixed maximum and minimum size of its.Then select Fixed size policy.But, I can increase or decrease size of subwindows.

[image: Fixed size policy]

How can I fix that?

Comment: I know this.Above image show subwindow properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen in `designer` you can't really select the subwindow, only the subwindow's content widget, so that's probably what your picture shows. So you only can change the subwindow's properties directly from your code, not in designer.

Example:

```
for subwin in mdiArea.subWindowList():
    subwin.setMinimumSize(289, 366)
    subwin.setMaximumSize(289, 366)
```